# How do I authenticate a user, retain a session, and then retrieve user specific data from supabase using only server side code?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, supabase

I'm using a POST request to my Nuxt3 with Supabase application, this is sent from a Raspberry Pi Pico W and is loaded with authentication credentials and an instruction. The post request is processed in server>api>order.js. Within this file I can log the user in like so:

```
let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        email: uid,
        password: pwd
    })
```

But I cannot seem to retain the session to retrieve data that possesses row level security allowing read access for only authenticated users. When I use:

```
const { data: logged, error: log_error } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
```

It returns 'session': 'None'.
So I'm wondering what is the correct way to do this, seeing as though I'm not using a browser as a client and its all happening on the server.
Here is the rest of my code:

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    // const query = getQuery(event)   // this is for GET requests only
    const body = await readBody(event)  // this is for POST requests only
    var uid = body.uid
    var pwd = body.pwd
    var order = body.order

    // access supabase
    // create supabase client for temporary anon
    const supabase = createClient(
        process.env.SUPABASE_URL, 
        process.env.SUPABASE_KEY,
        );

    // log in using the provided credentials
    let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        email: uid,
        password: pwd
    }) 

    if (error) {
        return error // send them back the error if the user is not authenticatable 
    } else {
        //extracting the necessary data
        const token = data.session.access_token // retrieve logged in users access token
        const uid = data.user.id // retrieve user id
        if (order == 'LED') {

            let { data: reactor_runs, error } = await supabase
            .from('reactor_runs')
            .select('program')
            .eq('owner', uid)

            // const { data: logged, error: log_error } = await supabase.auth.getSession()


            return {
                // status: supabase,
                uid: uid,
                pwd: pwd,
                order: order,
                error: error,
                token: token,
                uid: uid,
                order_response: reactor_runs[0].program.LED,
                logged_in: logged,
                logged_error: log_error
            }
        }
        else {
            return 'no result for your order'
        }
    }   
})
```

Thankyou very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out from [this thread](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/pull/340). I added this code above the creation of the client and it worked.

```
function inMemoryStorageProvider() {
    const items = new Map();
    return ({
      getItem: (key) => items.get(key),
      setItem: (key, value) => {
        items.set(key, value);
      },
      removeItem: (key) => {
        items.delete(key);
      },
    });
}
```

Then when I call the client creation method:

```
const supabase = createClient(
    process.env.SUPABASE_URL, 
    process.env.SUPABASE_KEY,
    {
        auth: {
            storage: inMemoryStorageProvider()
        }
    }
);
```

Now the session is retained across actions on the server and I can access the DB with auth restricted RLS enabled.